# Why my Node.js server connects my Desktop application and nothing else (emulator, apk)?

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, server, libgdx

I have created a new project using **Android Studio** with **libgdx** that tries to connect to a Node.js server that has a code like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var serv = server.listen(8080,function () {
    var port = serv.address().port;
    //a code I've found online to show on what adress im listening
    //"Example app listening at http://192.168.178.15:8080"
    require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) {
        console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', add, port);
    })
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("Connected!");
.
.
```

**My app code**

```
 public void connectSocket(){
            System.out.println("Connection to the socket has started");
            try {
                socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.178.15:8080");
                socket.connect();
                System.out.println("connected"); // says it's connected, but on app or emulator it's not
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
```

**The problem**
When i run my .jar or DesktopLauncher class everything works perfectly, I connect. The moment I use my phone or emulator i don't get an error, it tries to connect but nothing is logged about a connection. As if the app can't find a server.

**what I've tried**

I've tried all the things what i could find online:

- android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
- 
- turn off my firewall, allow node and all what is needed on there too
- changing differend ip adresses where to connect on my app such as "localhost", public ip, all the IP adresses I've found on ipconfig and internet, "o.o.o.o" (all of them worked on my computer .jar, or application through android studio)

  - portfoward 8080 but not sure if i did it right

  **I am using a router if that gives any clues what goes wrong**
  I'm trying this for few days now and I'm out of things to try.

Comment: When you try the phone, is it on the same network as the server (e.g. WiFi)?  Your server is presumably local and behind your local firewall so couldn't be connected to from a device on the outside network, particularly when using a local IP address such as 192.168.178.15.

Comment: Yes, my phone is on the same wifi as my laptop

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission in the android manifest?